# ModSecurity && Admin Ajax: Server locking up

Tags: ajax, htaccess, server

My server is throwing this error:

```
ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Software caused connection abort [uri "/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"]
```

Followed by this error until the server gets rebooted.

```
 Script timed out before returning headers: index.php
```

The company I host with is not being very helpful, and I have found a few answers regarding changing the settings for ModSecurity, but I don't know if I am comfortable doing that on a production server since I have never done it before.

I did ask the client, and they were uploading some images just before this happened, which means the error originated either from a client upload, or one of the few scripts we run through ajax on the front end.

Does anyone know if this is something we can solve with just setting a script timeout of some sort (I need to go in and see what the setting are now) or is something like whitelisting admin-ajax.php in ModSecurity the right direction? Maybe a different direction altogether?